# What is the difference between QEMU, KVM, Libvirt, and how to use with Vagrant? Are all 3 needed to work together?

Tags: vagrant, virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I've used Vagrant with Virtualbox before but VB is not working on this computer so I thought I would try a different approach, but I can't quite make sense of this cluster of software, what their uses are individually and interdependently... I know Vagrant boxes can have QEMU or Libvirt (or KVM?) providers, and there's qemu, and qemu-kvm, and vagrant-libvirt, and I just can't compartmentalize it all and their interconnection. I want to run virtual machines with synchronized folders on my host. Are all those required, and how? If not, why and how would one use all together? So I can better understand. On Debian 10

Comment: It might be helpful for you to get VirtualBox up and running since you already seem more familiar with it.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/208693/difference-between-kvm-and-qemu

Answer (score 42):

## Differences between QEMU, KVM, and Libvirt

[QEMU](https://www.qemu.org) is a machine (hardware) emulator.

[KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) is a kernel module for Linux to enable virtualization; this is the hypervisor.

QEMU can run without KVM but it can be quite a bit slower.

[libvirt](https://libvirt.org) is a virtualization library which wraps QEMU and KVM to provide APIs for use by other programs, such as [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com), which is a tool for creating virtualized development environments.

**Summary:**

- Vagrant uses libvirt.
- libvirt uses QEMU and KVM.

## How to use with Vagrant

First be sure to install the required dependencies:

```sh
apt-get build-dep vagrant ruby-libvirt
apt-get install qemu libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients ebtables dnsmasq-base
apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libvirt-dev zlib1g-dev ruby-dev
```

Source: https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt#installation

Then use the following command to run:

```sh
vagrant up --provider=libvirt
```

Or, use an environment variable instead:

```
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=libvirt
```

Source: https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt#start-vm

Comment: This is a great sum up! Thank you!

Comment: Nice summary. How does virtualbox or vmware fit in there?

Comment: Replace QEMU and KVM with either VirtualBox or VMware; both are hypervisors that come with their own drivers.

Comment: How does VMM (virtual machine manager) and virt-manager fit into this? Are they the hypervisor, the hypervisor GUI compared to KVM as the hypervisor CLI? Would a virtual machine running on the hypervisor KVM be called a VM then?